# DropDownList Selected Item Incorrect When Using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a number of dropdownlists embedded in a gridview. When I submit the page I loop through all the rows of the gridview and use the findcontrol method to get the dropdownlist e.g:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrItem in gvItems.Rows)
{    
    DropDownList ddlOption = gvrItem.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlOption") as DropDownList;
}
```

This works nicely, however when I try to get the selected item of the dropdownlist e.g:

```
ddlOption .SelectedItem.Text
```

It always returns the first item in the list rather than whats actually selecte din the page. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a quirk of .Net, if you fill the drop down list with ListItem's it won't carry those items into the ViewState. If you fill the drop down list with strings it will. Very odd I know.

e.g.:

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Add(new ListItem("text", "value")); <----Fails :(
ddl.Add("text"); <---- Works :)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this after the GridView has been databound.  Try calling it in the DataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrItem in gvItems.Rows)
    {    
        DropDownList ddlOption = gvrItem.Cells[2].FindControl("ddlOption") as DropDownList;
    }
    string selectedItem = ddlOption.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: oo is doing it after a postBack - there should be no need to rebind the gridView, as long as `EnableViewState` is set to `true`.

Comment: He is not saying that there is a need to rebind the gridview. He is is saying that the point in time in which the drop down is accessed may not be the best. After the gridview has been databound may be a better time to try to access the selected value.

Comment: I already do this, a button is clicked and the page_init method runs through first (This databinds the gridview and dynamically adds the drop down list to the gridview). Afterwards the buttons method runs through at which point the above code runs. The insane thing is I already so something similar on a seperate page. I'm struggling to see the different in the two